# What does maximize average log probability mean?

Tags: machine-learning, word-embeddings, word2vec, probability

In the word2vec paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.4546.pdf) that introduces the skip-gram algorithm we encounter this phrase:
[image]
which says that we maximize the average log probability.

Can someone help me understand how this formula maximizes? I don't have the intuition of what maximizing the probability means and why doing a sum over it would maximize it.

The only way I can think of maximizing is in the context of maximizing likelihood which you calculate using a probability density function.

Comment: This formula does not mazimize anything. **You** have to maximize it, usually with gradient descent.

Comment: @noe thanks, I think I get it now.

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer so your question can be marked as answered.

Comment: This is maximum likelihood just with a particular structure in the joint probability density function based on how skip gram tries to model each word c positions around the current word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula does not mazimize anything. **You** have to maximize it, usually with gradient descent.